# I made a datatable. But it takes every time the first column of my database/datatable. How can I take the second row/column of it?

Tags: c#

Can someone help me get the second row/column of my datatable because somehow it takes everytime the first one even if I say that I want the second one.

```
 int score = 1;
    private void pbBier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=patn4lj1;Uid=root;Pwd=root;");

        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select * from locaties";
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
        dtData.Load(reader);

                 //lblX.Text = rowX["X"].ToString();


        int xPos1 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[0][0]; //dit is de 4de rij van de 1ste kollom.        //  lblX.Text = rowX[colX].ToString();
        int xPos2 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[1][0];
        int xPos3 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[2][0];
        int xPos4 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[3][0];
        int xPos5 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[4][0];

        int yPos1 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[0][1];
        int yPos2 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[1][1];
        int yPos3 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[2][1];
        int yPos4 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[3][1];
        int yPos5 = (Int32)dtData.Rows[4][1];
      //  DataColumn colY = dtData.Columns[1];
      //  DataRow rowY = dtData.Rows[4];            //  lblY.Text = rowY["Y"].ToString();           
       // int YPos = rowY.ToString()[4];            // lblY.Text = rowY[colY].ToString();

        lblAantalScore.Text = score++.ToString();



        bool Gedaan = false;

        while (Gedaan == false)
        {            
            pbBier.Location = new Point(xPos1, yPos1);

            if (pbBier.Left == xPos1 && pbBier.Top == yPos1)
            {
                Gedaan = true; tmLoop.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("gefeliciteerd u hebt er " + lblTijd.Text + " Sec over gedaan"); tmLoop.Start();
            }


            if (Gedaan == true)
            {
                pbBier.Location = new Point(xPos2, yPos2);
            }

        //pbBier.Location = new Point(xPos3, yPos3);
        //pbBier.Location = new Point(xPos4, yPos4);
        //pbBier.Location = new Point(xPos5, yPos5);


        }



    }
```

**I edited it so can someone help me? if I click on the picturebox then it will go to the positions of the datareader." But what I want is that if I click on the picturebox for the second time then it has to go to the new coordinates of the datatable. can you help me? **

Comment: DataRow row = dtData.Rows[1] will give you the second row. It is 0-based. Object data = dtData.Rows[1][1] will give you the second column.

Comment: Look at my new edited code i want that my picturebox moves when i click the first time but when i click the second time it has to go to coordinats of Xpos and Ypos if you know what i mean. I hope you can help me?

Comment: Your problem is still confusing to me, what is the main goal? At first moves the picturebox, based on which positions? And the second time you click is not yet clear to me? You can clarify these doubts myself better so I can help you?

Comment: Look the first click on the picturebox the picturebox goes to the coordinates xPos1 and yPos1."Those xPos and yPos are my positions" then the second time i want to click on the picturebox, i want the picturebox to go to the second positions who is xPos2 and yPos2. And so further with xPos3, yPos3 and xPos4, yPos4. This: is my database information: i have a table who is named locaties, then in that table i have two columns, one is X and one is Y. In X are 5 numbers: 30, 111, 0, 350, 700 and in Y are also 5 numbers: 200, 22, 30, 150, 300.

Comment: So it means that xPos1= column x.number30. yPos= columnY.200. I Hope you know what I mean and so you can help me as fast as possible! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead you use:

```
Object data = dtData.Rows[3][1];
int xPos = data.ToString()[1];
```

use:

```
int xPos = (Int32)dtData.Rows[3][0];//you know which access fourth row and first column?
```

Comment: Hey now i have a problem because i said:" if I click on the picturebox then it will go to the positions of the datareader." But what I want is that if I click on the picturebox for the second time then it has to go to the new coordinates of the datatable.  can you help me?

Comment: My pictureboxes name is pbBier i dont really now what XAML you mean?

Comment: Look at my new edited code i want that my picturebox moves when i click the first time but when i click the second time it has to go to coordinats of Xpos and Ypos if you know what i mean. I hope you can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your `DataTable` could to be accessed in the form of `array of muti-dimension`. For example:

```
dtData.Rows[0][0]; // access the first row and first column
dtData.Rows[0][1]; // access the first row and second column
dtData.Rows[0][2]; // access the first row and third column
dtData.Rows[1][0]; // access the second row and first column
dtData.Rows[1][1]; // access the second row and second column
dtData.Rows[1][2]; // access the second row and third column
```

If you need can go all fields returned using two nested `for` statement:

```
for(int i = 0;i < dtData.Rows.Count;i++)//travels the rows
{
     for(int j = 0;j < dtData.Rows.Count;j++)//travels the columns
     {
          var valueField = dtData.Rows[i][j];//access the value of current field
     }
}
```

Comment: But when i type this then is shows me this error Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement D:\Programeren\blokboek4\week8\ZoetebierBlendiAO1C2\ZoetebierBlendiAO1C2\Form1.cs 58 13 ZoetebierBlendiAO1C2

Comment: Your select statement is seeking only 'X' column, so if you try to access a column at index 1 will an error occurs because you returned only one column, not two.

Comment: oke now i did this  command.CommandText = "select * from locaties"; but still got an error: index out of range.

Comment: Im new on stackoverflow so i dont know how to update

Comment: edit your question and and replace your old code by the current code.

Comment: to get your posX of row 4 and first column, do so: var posX = dtData.Rows[3][0] as String; You understand?

Comment: i dont work with var but i will try then i will let you know thx

Comment: place string instead var

Comment: Im sorry man i dont understand your way maybe if you show me but i cant solve this sry. :(

Comment: Look at my new edited code i want that my picturebox moves when i click the first time but when i click the second time it has to go to coordinats of Xpos and Ypos if you know what i mean. I hope you can help me?

Comment: Look by the first click on the picturebox the picturebox goes to the coordinates xPos1 and yPos1."Those xPos and yPos are my positions" then the second time i want to click on the picturebox, i want the picturebox to go to the second positions who is xPos2 and yPos2. And so further with xPos3, yPos3 and xPos4, yPos4.                                  This: is my database information: i have a table who is named locaties, then in that table i have two columns, one is X and one is Y. In X are 5 numbers: 30, 111, 0, 350, 700 and in Y are also 5 numbers: 200, 22, 30, 150, 300.

Comment: So it means that xPos1= column x.number30. yPos= columnY.200. I Hope you know what I mean and so you can help me as fast as possible! thank you.